# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read

Tags: sftp

While connecting SFTP I am getting following error.

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read

Please guide me,

Comment: A bit rough. You should motivate people to help you by asking kindly. AMHA they will will to spend as much time to answer you that you spent typing your question.

Comment: and you should use code formating when writting a code question they use quite standard Markdown syntax

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the code which is getting the exception, and include the stacktrace which goes with the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think the answer is trivial. You are not able to open a stream i.e. the sftp connexion is not estabmlished sucessfully. Check wit IT team or support if there is firewalls or so and that can see you arriving on the server.